# App is crashing on launch screen(on iPad 10.2)

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, ipv6, thread-abort

My app get rejected because crashing on launch screen saying that it is taking to much time while launching(Checked by watchdog Timer).
But it is working fine on my side while running with xcode.

Along with this Apple send me a message that is:
 "During review, your app failed to launch on iPad running iOS 10.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network."

I had checked this on iPad(10.2) with IPv6 network, it is working fine.

I don't able to understand how to find the issue in the below crash that where is app crashing.

Here's the crash report:

```
Date/Time:           2016-12-12 07:22:47.2580 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-12-12 07:22:47.0532 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x19462e1c0 0x19306855c 0x19462e108 0x19a98359c 0x19a7e4444 0x19a5b653c 0x19a481d48 0x19a53bca0 0x19a53bb78 0x19a53aec0 0x19a53a90c 0x19a53a4c0 0x19a53a424 0x19a47f220 0x19793f188 0x197933e64 0x197933d24 0x1978b07ec 0x1978d7c58 0x1978d8678 0x1945db7dc 0x1945d940c 0x194508068 0x19a4ed2b0 0x19a4e8034 0x100080b7c 0x1934ec5b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001935fe014 0x1935df000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c6450 0x1936c1000 + 21584
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001935723e0 0x19350f000 + 406496
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019303d2d4 0x19303c000 + 4820
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019305acc0 0x19303c000 + 126144
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193068844 0x193060000 + 34884
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019305766c 0x19303c000 + 112236
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193057234 0x19303c000 + 111156
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019306871c 0x193060000 + 34588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001945080bc 0x1944ff000 + 37052
10  UIKit                           0x000000019a4ed2b0 0x19a472000 + 504496
11  UIKit                           0x000000019a4e8034 0x19a472000 + 483380
12  Y-LogApp                        0x0000000100080b7c 0x10007c000 + 19324
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001934ec5b8 0x1934e8000 + 17848

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: MyCustomQueue
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001935fde1c 0x1935df000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c39c0 0x1936c1000 + 10688
2   Foundation                      0x000000019506a590 0x19500d000 + 382352
3   Foundation                      0x000000019502da0c 0x19500d000 + 133644
4   Foundation                      0x0000000195031a3c 0x19500d000 + 150076
5   Y-LogApp                        0x0000000100082ba4 0x10007c000 + 27556
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934b9200 0x1934b8000 + 4608
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934b91c0 0x1934b8000 + 4544
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934c7444 0x1934b8000 + 62532
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934bc9a8 0x1934b8000 + 18856
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934c7940 0x1934b8000 + 63808
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934c938c 0x1934b8000 + 70540
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934c90ec 0x1934b8000 + 69868
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c22b8 0x1936c1000 + 4792
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c1da4 0x1936c1000 + 3492

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c1da0 0x1936c1000 + 3488

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c1da0 0x1936c1000 + 3488

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c1da0 0x1936c1000 + 3488

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001935e016c 0x1935df000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001935dffdc 0x1935df000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001945dbcec 0x1944ff000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001945d9908 0x1944ff000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000194508048 0x1944ff000 + 36936
5   Foundation                      0x0000000195019a8c 0x19500d000 + 51852
6   Foundation                      0x000000019503a57c 0x19500d000 + 185724
7   UIKit                           0x000000019ae62a2c 0x19a472000 + 10422828
8   Foundation                      0x000000019511747c 0x19500d000 + 1090684
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c4850 0x1936c1000 + 14416
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c4760 0x1936c1000 + 14176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936c1dac 0x1936c1000 + 3500

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001780ffab7
    x4: 0x000000019305bbc3   x5: 0x000000016fd83580   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000193589772  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b8e7bc40  x21: 0x000000016fd83580  x22: 0x00000001b8e82bb8  x23: 0x0000000000000004
   x24: 0x0000000174003c60  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fd83be0   fp: 0x000000016fd834e0   lr: 0x00000001936c6450
    sp: 0x000000016fd834c0   pc: 0x00000001935fe014 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x10007c000 - 0x10062ffff Y-LogApp arm64  <3bdc43b8fee6366ca78d4b7a097b2852> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/656C5222-D3D4-4151-810F-27D45BC927F3/Y-LogApp.app/Y-LogApp
0x1007b4000 - 0x1007e3fff dyld arm64  <f5a894bbb0cc38b1930add2172007394> /usr/lib/dyld
0x192fe4000 - 0x192fe5fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <7f6df0ff83ca38c5bd2451d798c6619b> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x192fe6000 - 0x19303bfff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <ad5eb3d0e134370ab9ab52e3979ac239> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x19303c000 - 0x19305cfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <514938651ad43466908d2d993b588bec> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x193060000 - 0x193439fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <cfe85583868931d48088e908339f76c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x19343a000 - 0x19343efff libcache.dylib arm64  <3f13f51a773b35c1ba38ca66ad803e89> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x19343f000 - 0x19344afff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <dc02b342926033248c75ef323b51edc4> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x19344b000 - 0x19344efff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <6bcab91bf9f1390eac1d038f9a2699d6> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x19344f000 - 0x193456fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <0c337bd80f193fbdb28313e4eaf758ea> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x193457000 - 0x1934b7fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <3b0c9c05a798360ebc821fbe2f50b95c> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1934b8000 - 0x1934e7fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <3840477f1dcb32c5be29d805a0b43d93> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1934e8000 - 0x1934ecfff libdyld.dylib arm64  <39aaa2dbe1a1313c9c838cc0268a2ea0> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1934ed000 - 0x1934edfff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <04e27dee99a031ba8a7124b6b72c909c> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1934ee000 - 0x1934f3fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <a3797232763a393faa9bf3cf5a871e0c> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1934f4000 - 0x1934f5fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <28e912626c483873a21e720a9e6e31d3> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1934f6000 - 0x19350dfff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <36b03a6fe92b36a687a31254e4eef33b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x19350e000 - 0x19350efff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <1c111df9108e3d0f90cfbe5a197ae4a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x19350f000 - 0x19358dfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <93efa69c71cb30a092cc72cf178f2e65> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x19358e000 - 0x193592fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <e57ff277342c3b22b2da2fecef617b23> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x193593000 - 0x193598fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <41d8a1a4127b3cccb4cb93f337b922d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x193599000 - 0x19359afff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <5f536aa39a3d34079d3277708c4b5f3b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x19359b000 - 0x1935b3fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <5b2a44a2d8ed3cc6aaccbae99e805dd4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x1935b4000 - 0x1935bafff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <dd0a055b1bea35e7a371d2a134aa4cb4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x1935bb000 - 0x1935defff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <b372a8a239223d20b9cb13bd4efe0790> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1935df000 - 0x193603fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <3bb31dbc99853fa4b33f4948c9e2af64> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x193604000 - 0x193630fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <03779efeda81345586b8fd3d69323160> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x193631000 - 0x19364cfff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <2828f6cf98c631969e22ae3aaf0c9289> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x19364d000 - 0x1936a4fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <5e487af9f3a03dd8ba7833602b554363> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x1936a5000 - 0x1936aefff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <db6affcb13a53af58cbe796b7ef935bd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x1936af000 - 0x1936b9fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <a86d8c5a0bea3666a69ecfc6b81a2fe7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1936ba000 - 0x1936c0fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <14630f9a42813c0a819764b8ada8383b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1936c1000 - 0x1936cafff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <548d3d6a3b5738f2820e0382c8d77c0e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1936cb000 - 0x1936cefff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <4bb12da1ae923ba38e60e63ced4c0ad0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x1936cf000 - 0x1936d6fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <295884acb7c63956892540ada2cd23a4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x1936d7000 - 0x1936f5fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <8c79d49939f33d33b5a29474667934b8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1936f6000 - 0x1936fbfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <f4dc6306fe0d3a819f67667eff14553c> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x1936fc000 - 0x1936fcfff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <027cf263be4933609dd97728b329a18b> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x1936fd000 - 0x193723fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <a0c4e91da2c839b59ecbbb7aa397e244> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x193724000 - 0x19393efff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <e53c0577ce0b38afb83a2b7a54b4a390> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x19393f000 - 0x19394ffff libz.1.dylib arm64  <a8ab1654147738bda28160886a3a5df1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x1944ff000 - 0x194882fff CoreFoundation arm64  <d72e357f5b3337aa9693522564a6032e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x194883000 - 0x194893fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <a964c720dd6c3b828b3490d0da04b5f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x194894000 - 0x194894fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <e6230b7a7ea4327893377cb661336e25> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x194895000 - 0x194910fff IOKit arm64  <97df8046f49d3a3c9a28ad1c89ec90a9> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x194911000 - 0x194931fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <e9c324bb1aa63739946642d6cf3c2dd0> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x194932000 - 0x194a1cfff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <30ee067a18313bb18a3ad40b0dd4ccc1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x194a1d000 - 0x194aaafff Security arm64  <0e0e9f42cb41335ab94eee731c6a4db8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x194aab000 - 0x194b15fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <d2744fb1dcd93a0e938f5065e7ac4039> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x194b16000 - 0x194c2afff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <a54037ad22f1329998d318a227192323> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x194c2b000 - 0x194f9bfff CFNetwork arm64  <516a98d92600361d89748c8c865aeb9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x194f9c000 - 0x194facfff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <4035caebd18030b698192b8c92fed3ea> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x194fad000 - 0x194fc5fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <690a1d50cfad332c9ffce151555cf5d3> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x194fc6000 - 0x194fe0fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <b80cb8a907773d08997be69dc6340070> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x194fe1000 - 0x19500afff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <104744e9187837d8ba843c443f4a98cb> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x19500b000 - 0x19500cfff liblangid.dylib arm64  <70c15ad0050435899c857e8844aedd04> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x19500d000 - 0x1952dbfff Foundation arm64  <8c727aea9f34365fb2fe552669585011> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1952dc000 - 0x195388fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <6ea5b89378513f2e846e31871b410a0b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x195389000 - 0x1956cbfff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <0646b0c159c93102926cdf9221d11568> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x1956cc000 - 0x19596efff vImage arm64  <c17d2e052c6f36349a2cae4dd3a5aee1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x19596f000 - 0x195991fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <20d445b170e730d1888141bfaa6be593> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x195992000 - 0x1959a6fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <930cd329b8ea391fb226d14819375940> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1959a7000 - 0x1959b8fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <2ee1252ee69e3ec587cc93364d05fd4d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x1959b9000 - 0x195a31fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <43133d90a9fd32e681cee537ebc0f154> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x195a32000 - 0x195a32fff vecLib arm64  <1b404e41514b383285c36288ece53c9b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x195a33000 - 0x195a33fff Accelerate arm64  <3c43596ee1eb3048a65bfc8b3bb05c0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x195a34000 - 0x195f81fff CoreGraphics arm64  <1b546c1bd4eb334eb850e116b430e550> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x195f82000 - 0x195f96fff GraphicsServices arm64  <6d8ec4c741ae3332ae4854a3c69f9c68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x195f97000 - 0x195fe2fff AppSupport arm64  <caf9b40929c73faeaaf25b33ad2a0647> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x195fe3000 - 0x196105fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <8172d8e133d23395bbfa078d6a44f089> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x196106000 - 0x19615dfff BaseBoard arm64  <b33d2bf343f43bc5b5a7d0d4b4dd5f5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x19615e000 - 0x196169fff AssertionServices arm64  <7610246b4f683b77811d43811f30465d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x19616a000 - 0x196196fff BackBoardServices arm64  <d463b45d03f13e6987eb6bdae3bf941c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x19619b000 - 0x1961eafff FrontBoardServices arm64  <c559fb4fa9ba31319bc7b1ba9c4ba308> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1961ee000 - 0x196221fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <d388e2d75b523b748f195d9a3d27d278> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x196222000 - 0x196236fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <270099c5284b31a1906053816b6cec02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x196237000 - 0x19623ffff IOSurface arm64  <ef7ac073d6943dc78d9fd3440e0348d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x196240000 - 0x19624bfff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <9b0b0e6f40d33edfaf15399d4bad8121> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x19624c000 - 0x196261fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <66e9fd41492333dfab588cc2021fbebc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x196262000 - 0x196264fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <4e2f4feb26af3b22ae56f1730fb8a133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x196265000 - 0x1962a5fff AppleJPEG arm64  <87de27bcf04536ae846760442b89cad1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x1962a6000 - 0x196839fff ImageIO arm64  <e16442857870346fbe11e98073358914> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x19683a000 - 0x196840fff TCC arm64  <225b54db9ae3396fa00a310bf3310765> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x196841000 - 0x196845fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <5eae0ee54d7238d38c60df504164bd7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x196846000 - 0x196852fff PowerLog arm64  <752721ed2da73535b1f7e61d50c0026b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x196853000 - 0x1968bbfff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <878f4d0fcf5830a984dfecf58c639d0a> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x1968bc000 - 0x1968cefff CommonUtilities arm64  <0d35a47331413981a51a592a4b4c3302> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x1968cf000 - 0x1968e3fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <388d583a262f3c8fbbb0453ff8d17426> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x1968e4000 - 0x196b7efff CoreData arm64  <8ed91a98ce0b37208579ff6ed712895c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x196b7f000 - 0x196b82fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <760ae35b9c1932edbd00150e7a98233a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x196b83000 - 0x196b88fff IOAccelerator arm64  <89785d94951d32b1a745248a1bf25467> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x196b89000 - 0x196b8afff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <5affde13a3443280a5965cd5348d5149> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x196b8b000 - 0x196b8efff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <893e81d4d84e3946974e360cb29cda11> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x196b8f000 - 0x196bd2fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <8b343c8b5c2537d08c7e1885354b1215> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x196bd3000 - 0x196bddfff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <0058e13e9a2f382eb9cde69f36b7ff62> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x196bde000 - 0x196be5fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <2355c7f4d2a231e4be5d5b373305da9d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x196be6000 - 0x196be6fff libmetal_timestamp.dylib arm64  <8faeb09acb873be09949113fa3bd09ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
0x196be7000 - 0x196c44fff Metal arm64  <20393a96a3363112a27a4d6b3c665ff6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x196c45000 - 0x196c4ffff OpenGLES arm64  <d08c2b2cceff3d5c84e5c9a0c36d8616> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x196c50000 - 0x196c74fff CoreVideo arm64  <ffe63a1da77632a299fb49c0d1a5d1ae> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x196c75000 - 0x196c77fff OAuth arm64  <cae3b485d0ab36258111405e19ac90a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x196c78000 - 0x196cb6fff Accounts arm64  <8048b7450119347d8da167b5c1335450> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x196cb7000 - 0x196da9fff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <73b7dfe2c5ff3976a8ab4296f054e0e5> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x196daa000 - 0x196ef9fff CoreAudio arm64  <a43b5272ad823963928419f52a18b111> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x196efa000 - 0x196efdfff UserFS arm64  <729dba0a9bbf381a843c48d49ca6c480> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x196efe000 - 0x197008fff CoreMedia arm64  <3fe516f880a13a9b9bf918a198b46e28> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x197009000 - 0x19700ffff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <0b8bc03133f8336e97a3ae07b8147102> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x197010000 - 0x19709cfff CoreTelephony arm64  <88ceb856f0ad32af94b11d5b48e19d7e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x19709d000 - 0x1971a7fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <8a900cd98c5b31398f9ba6149c569e5b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x1971a8000 - 0x197237fff VideoToolbox arm64  <3aca3dde0dbb3872bc95038b03502025> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x197238000 - 0x197238fff FontServices arm64  <ba687761d8e73468be35c7f3d84fa306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x197239000 - 0x197385fff CoreText arm64  <02cfb5fa81a83126aa5fcf6157613256> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x197386000 - 0x1973a0fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <f48cb8f315d83384914b983367ba1f18> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x1973a1000 - 0x1973c9fff PersistentConnection arm64  <333e3815b7723c56be80d58acce5b64e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x1973ca000 - 0x1973d0fff DataMigration arm64  <a1d17e9bda9b318485a11a8c8c207875> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x1973d1000 - 0x197828fff AudioToolbox arm64  <e19ea620e15c3f0cb40524b722dd5087> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x197829000 - 0x197a01fff QuartzCore arm64  <bf63fba959473e548ed5f6e4db40e3ae> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x197a02000 - 0x197a08fff Netrb arm64  <9cb22261041c35fb8c6e0a9cf49e67a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x197a09000 - 0x197a19fff libcmph.dylib arm64  <da7029d8e489384eba1a9af5cd14682c> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x197a1a000 - 0x197a3afff libmis.dylib arm64  <b86c97bf93d630dcb3a4005dd18405db> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x197a3b000 - 0x197b2cfff LanguageModeling arm64  <be6ee8c894f03940bb8d9f8e56614c42> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x197b2d000 - 0x197c13fff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <2ed5cecbd4fc3f85bc1244e1cb12e039> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x197c14000 - 0x197c2afff libmarisa.dylib arm64  <6dc2792a342c3ef89643cc735997e56b> /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib
0x197c2b000 - 0x197cfbfff ProofReader arm64  <172b6a42b4ab3bad96828ecefd3b9530> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x197cfc000 - 0x197d06fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <842aa10100d13d1688dcd6d43d3ed550> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x197d07000 - 0x197d17fff MobileAsset arm64  <b64f721801053489b4a29f707c930b31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x197d18000 - 0x197d89fff ColorSync arm64  <dbaae646d6a935feb38b961d234a0fcf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x197d8a000 - 0x197df9fff MetalPerformanceShaders arm64  <71664ffbbd713c43bb9f1aed5409c131> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x197dfa000 - 0x198229fff FaceCore arm64  <3acc58da74e433ef872fcbc74ef3b4f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x19822a000 - 0x1982a5fff Quagga arm64  <a9e8152fb85d3884a7a8eae0db28789b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x1982a6000 - 0x19846ffff CoreImage arm64  <c57d3bcefeca33c28835754b1f411883> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x198470000 - 0x1984bbfff TextInput arm64  <ce037eecb165313ea83dc7619902614b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x1984bc000 - 0x1984ccfff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <ad932566e85f3a509bf61a9d6baccf1b> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x1984dc000 - 0x198e30fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <218fe9fe272c312bae4bf25250451a5f> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x198e31000 - 0x19904afff StoreServices arm64  <ff11f8f89db033a1ae2050201f79752e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x19904b000 - 0x19a13cfff WebCore arm64  <9a528dd69fea3d1e91cdbe233f9aa2ab> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x19a13d000 - 0x19a166fff libxslt.1.dylib arm64  <7444cfa4c6c73e1f979308e941d9ef75> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x19a167000 - 0x19a248fff WebKitLegacy arm64  <fbdca0f275923d8e9772474cb6541dc2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x19a249000 - 0x19a311fff CoreUI arm64  <9c0d0f2a481634d09f894167603b8e1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x19a312000 - 0x19a339fff DictionaryServices arm64  <c7ba92c140f13acbbd77e28f37e308e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x19a33a000 - 0x19a33bfff HangTracer arm64  <6865168113b53a28b5412d51379e16b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HangTracer.framework/HangTracer
0x19a33c000 - 0x19a38cfff PhysicsKit arm64  <b78dfc9e358f3687a16f74f0498db603> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x19a38d000 - 0x19a465fff UIFoundation arm64  <6d2159d7532c365d9ebc5cf3d2acdb87> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x19a472000 - 0x19b1fffff UIKit arm64  <7ef942f43c3e3e4aa6cec127b68ecbab> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x19b200000 - 0x19b228fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <0668bc33dc133b49b1461abda1ea968f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x19b229000 - 0x19b24efff DataAccessExpress arm64  <5fbf9ad4bb6635e3b6dee2038037db4e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x19b24f000 - 0x19b270fff NetworkStatistics arm64  <f997854e71c93bf1873aeaf8615f9884> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x19b271000 - 0x19b2f9fff AddressBook arm64  <5c11f57b219530288cb2954862ed23f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x19b2fa000 - 0x19b42efff CoreMotion arm64  <f87d9d1a138d3aa989c550dc9dc2c66d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x19b42f000 - 0x19b45cfff CacheDelete arm64  <c4057897ab23369e8fe7a14f687818cf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/CacheDelete
0x19b45d000 - 0x19b46afff CoreAUC arm64  <d88142d627d33b7f86446c5a1170babb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x19b46b000 - 0x19ba4efff MediaToolbox arm64  <bd92166d9cce382fae200e4c6ef1cf1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x19ba4f000 - 0x19bbf5fff Celestial arm64  <e6cf92965c4d310ba8864b92ab64be98> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x19bbf6000 - 0x19bc05fff IntlPreferences arm64  <7062c1f3645137bfbf44f20531931a8d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntlPreferences.framework/IntlPreferences
0x19bc06000 - 0x19bc08fff CoreDuetDebugLogging arm64  <eba94238c28e3cd5ae4caf73900227ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x19bc09000 - 0x19bc1dfff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol arm64  <f561fda7671b34fd83890a0eb03a57a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
0x19bc1e000 - 0x19bcf3fff CoreDuet arm64  <b275d881a2143153b7e3ecd86421de2c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x19bcf4000 - 0x19bea2fff AVFoundation arm64  <380f25440bc6399ebf077523c12b6086> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x19bea3000 - 0x19bed5fff libtidy.A.dylib arm64  <104c07ea5281354f99d7d86ce07ddc2c> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x19bed6000 - 0x19bf3cfff IMFoundation arm64  <9d8462f7c4163fa0b2f5a8b808b1950c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x19bf3d000 - 0x19c5c3fff GeoServices arm64  <570b5a1a299e3a98a2b0dcfd5028d7c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x19c5c4000 - 0x19c5c5fff DiagnosticLogCollection arm64  <6c702260771b3c378bd7b5304f82211e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
```

Comment: just updated.. check now

Comment: what was your console output during crash?

Comment: @Bluewings - while running on xcode it is working fine ... This issue arises from apple side during testing, So i just have the crash report only which apple forwarded to me

Comment: you have to run the app on real iPad and check it

Comment: yeah.. i had done that and its is working fine without crashing on my iPad  but when i download it from testFlight and click on open then it ask for push notification confirmation and after clicking on ok my App goes into background mode... i am not able to understand what to do

Comment: so it is problem with push notification. make sure your App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal. Then, sign your app with a distribution provisioning profile that includes the aps-environment entitlement. This will create the correct signature and re-submit the app to testlight and verify

Comment: i checked that too. there is no such issue with push notification or with provisioning profile. I think this is because of watchdog timer, Apple mentioned that this app is taking time while launching but i don't feel so. I had tested with time profiler also.. but nothing works

Comment: The next step is to [symbolicate the crash report](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1460892/1068283).

Comment: @MichaelHampton The crash report attached with the question was first symbolicated then i attached it.. if it is not symbolicated then please provide way to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had made some changes in my push notification code and remove all the instance of view controller from Appdelegate.

Now my app is approved.